# Facebook: Problems due to schemeless // iframe src for like buttons

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have a problem with the Facebook [jsssdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) in the way it loads the iframes.
Our app is bundled with stbuild into an iOS app (besides being served over http as a mobiel web page).

In "iOS mode", the origin of your app is `file:///[...]/index.html`. The Facebook scheme-less url style is breaking for us, because `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` translates to `file:///connect...`. Therefore, we updated our snippet to:

```
(function(d, s, id, debug){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + bp.lib.Facebook.getCurrentLocale() + "/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk', /*debug*/ false));
```

However, the facebook sdk will create iframes for the individual like buttons. These also have an `<iframe src="//..." >`, and break. I didn't find a way to enforce the sdk to use url schemes.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: As a “quick fix” you could generate the iframe code yourself … (if you don’t need to listen for edge.create events).

Comment: +1, just use the iframe version of the plugin yourself?

Comment: We don't need to listen to any events. However, I would prefer to use the SDK anyways, because it will be easier to integrate as we dynamically add like buttons to the view. I'd suggest you formulate this as your answer, and if there is no way to set the URL scheme to use with the JS SDK I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `https://` in all the iframe code and other files you include on your web page. It will then still work correctly over a regular `http` connection and with `https` connections. It's the best way to prevent issues like this.